# Next-Auth Middleware Disables Register Page for Non-authenticated users

Tags: authentication, next.js, middleware, next-auth

So I implemented Next-Auth and added a middleware that disables the /register and /login routes if the user is authenticated. But if the user is not authenticated and wants to register, they can't access the /register route and get forwarded to /login.

```js
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt'
import { withAuth } from 'next-auth/middleware'
import { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export default async function middleware(
    req: NextRequest,
    event: NextFetchEvent
) {
    const token = await getToken({ req })
    const isAuthenticated = !!token

    if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/login') && isAuthenticated) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/profile', req.url))
    }

    const authMiddleware = await withAuth({
        pages: {
            signIn: `/login`,
        },
    })

    // @ts-expect-error
    return authMiddleware(req, event)
}

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/login', '/register'],
}
```

Tried few variations of `if` checks and played with the `matcher` but the issue still persisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved it.

```js
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt'
import { withAuth } from 'next-auth/middleware'
import { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export default async function middleware(
    req: NextRequest,
    event: NextFetchEvent
) {
    const token = await getToken({ req })
    const isAuthenticated = !!token

    if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/login') && isAuthenticated) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/profile', req.url))
    }
    if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/register') && isAuthenticated) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/profile', req.url))
    }


    const authMiddleware = await withAuth({
        pages: {
            signIn: req.nextUrl.pathname,
        },
    })

    // @ts-expect-error
    return authMiddleware(req, event)
}

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/login', '/register'],
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).